# Spotify App: How to access webcam?

Tags: javascript, html, spotify

I tried to access the webcam via js/html (getUserMedia). The app runs on my apache machine but not as a static file within spotify app.

**Any ideas?**

```
function start()
{
    if ((typeof window === 'undefined') || (typeof navigator === 'undefined')) log('This page needs a Web browser with the objects window.* and navigator.*!');
    else if (!(video && canvas)) log('HTML context error!');
    else
    {
        log('Get user media…');
        if (navigator.getUserMedia) navigator.getUserMedia({video:true}, gotStream, noStream);
        else if (navigator.oGetUserMedia) navigator.oGetUserMedia({video:true}, gotStream, noStream);
        else if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) navigator.mozGetUserMedia({video:true}, gotStream, noStream);
        else if (navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({video:true}, gotStream, noStream);
        else if (navigator.msGetUserMedia) navigator.msGetUserMedia({video:true, audio:false}, gotStream, noStream);
        else log('getUserMedia() not available from your Web browser!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this isn't supported in the Spotify Apps environment at the moment.